# Update sql database without blanks fields

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to figure out a way for my program not to update the sql database if some fields are blank when I hit the submit form. Right now when I submit it to the sql database, if the fields are blank, it updates it as blank. Is there a way for my code not to behave like this?

Thanks

```
        //field names in the table
        string update = @"UPDATE Master_List
                        SET Date_Complete1 = @Date_Complete1, Pass_Fail = @Pass_Fail, CRC_Number = @CRC_Number, QN_Number = @QN_Number, Notes = @Notes WHERE Job_Number = @Job_Number"; //parameter names

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) //using allows disposing of low level resources
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();//open new connection
                command = new SqlCommand(update, conn); // create the new sql command object
                                                        // Read value from form and save to the table
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Job_Number", jobTxt.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Pass_Fail", comboBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Date_Complete1", opBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"CRC_Number", crcTxt.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"QN_Number", qnTxt.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Notes", notesTxt.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Push form into the table
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // If there is something wrong, show the user message
            }
        }
```

Comment: Validate the input (the Controls' values) before upating the database?

Comment: If database values are not supposed to be blank, the database should have a constraint. Don't rely on the front-end to keep data valid.

Comment: Retrieve the object from the database first, then check if the form inputs are blank, then you replace them by the object values you got from the database. By the way, I recommend using Entity Framework. Give it a try..

Comment: dont directly pick from the textbox.store in a local variable and then check using `IsNullorBlank`

Comment: The parameter's name should be "@Job_Number" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to update some of the fields if one or more fields are blank, then you can do this:

```
UPDATE Master_List
SET Date_Complete1 = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Date_Complete1,''),Date_Complete1),
    Pass_Fail = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Pass_Fail,''),Pass_Fail),
    CRC_Number = ISNULL(NULLIF(@CRC_Number,''),CRC_Number),
    QN_Number = ISNULL(NULLIF(@QN_Number,''),QN_Number),
    Notes = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Notes,''),Notes)
WHERE Job_Number = @Job_Number
```

If you don't want any fields to update if any fields are blank, then just check them in an if statement.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Perform checks on your input data before your sql code is executed.

simply return out of the function if any checks you want to do fail e.g.

`If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable to check))`
          ... Return or configure error message for user ...

Or perform some logic to show the user you dont want blank fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to validate that you should change your database field properties to do that task.
if you want to do this with some code you should add something like this:

```
   bool val = true;
      if (jobTxt.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) {
          val = false;
      }
if(val==true){
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else{
MessageBox.Show("Some field is empty")
}
```

and repite the sentence if for each textbox you want to do a validation.
i hope this help you.
You can say which textbox is empty on the else sentences on the textbox.